# Problemas con los operadores logicos (or y and)

Tags: python

Hola estoy intentando hacer un bucle que se repite hasta que uno de los dos valores llega a 0 o menos, pero para al azar, todas las veces que cargo el codigo uno de los dos valores llega a menos de 0 antes que el otro pero no paran de bajar hasta que el otro llega a 0

```
import random
valor1 = 56
valor2 = 75
while valor1 > 0 or valor2 > 0:
  valor1 -= random.randint(1,8)
  valor2 -= random.randint(1,12)
  print(valor1, valor2)
```

Comment: Al usar or le dices al bucle que continue mientras uno de los valores o ambos sean >0. Si quieres que en el momento que uno no lo sea pare debes usar and.

Comment: Gracias!! no estaba entendiendo bien como funcionaba.

Comment: Te sugiero tomar por costumbre usar signos de agrupación explícitos para mejorar la legibilidad y evitarte errores difíciles de detectar

Answer (score 2):

cuando usas **`'or'`** tenes que tener en cuenta que se va a seguir mientras uno o ambas comprobaciones sean verdaderas.

En tu caso tendrias que usar **`'and'`**, para que cuando una de las dos comprobaciones sea falsa termine la ejecucion.

Resumen:

- `Or` = se ejecuta con al menos una comprobacion verdadera

---

```
true or false = true
```

- `And` = se ejecuta cuando las dos comprobaciones sean verdaderas

---

```
true and true = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Qué tal, deberías estar utilizando and en vez de or en tu condición del while.

Prueba y verás.

Esto porque el conector or devuelve True cuando al menos una de las expresiones es verdadera, en cambio and devuelve True únicamente si ambas expresiones son verdaderas, al instante que una de las expresiones deja de ser cierta zas, la expresión devolverá False.

Saludos!